# Compute the divided difference $p[x_0, x_1, . . . , x_{n+1}]$ where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

So I know that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then the $n$th divided difference of $f(x)$ is a constant.

$$f [x_0,x_1,...,x_n]= \frac{ f [x_0,x_1,...,x_n] - f [x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1}]}{x_n-x_0} $$

Now, my question  requires me to compute the divided difference of $p[x_0, x_1, . . . , x_{n+1}]$. Does the $n+1$ change anything? From my understanding, this is just the leading term of the interpolating polynomial of $f$ over $x_0, x_1, . . . , x_{n+1}$. I'm just a little lost on what I need to compute. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DietrichBurde my apologies. fixed

Comment: Not yet fixed - try MathJax instead.

Comment: What do you know about the degree of the divided difference if the function is a polynomial?